# How do I filter objects in javascript similar to GroupBy and Having in this SQL query?

Tags: javascript, sql, underscore.js

I have a SQL query that works for filtering on a list of conditions (attributes), but I need to move the functionality to strictly client-side. I have the full dataset on the client and just need to know the most effective and efficient way to simulate the logic on my JSON/JS objects.

```
SELECT id
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id
HAVING Count(id) >= @VALUES_COUNT
WHERE condition_column IN( @VALUES )
```

This is for an attribute (tag) based filter. I can say something like this in SQL:

```
SELECT fruit.fruitId
FROM fruit
INNER JOIN fruitAttributes ON fruitAttributes.fruitId = fruit.fruitId
GROUP BY fruit.fruitId
HAVING Count(fruit.fruitId) >= 2
WHERE fruitAttributes.id IN( 1, 2 )
```

*Imagine fruitAttrubutes 1 is "HasSeeds" and 2 is "MakesJuice" for instance

My result is the fruitIds where all conditions match.

The libraries at my disposal are jQuery and underscore/lodash.js

EDIT:

The objects on the client-side are being transported from .NET as JSON in this structure.

```
[{ 
  fruitId: 1,
  name: "Granny Smith Apple",
  color: "orange",
  flattenedAttributes: "[HasSeeds][MakesJuice]",
  attributes : [1, 2] 
}, 
{
  fruitId: 2,
  name: "Banana",
  color: "yellow",
  flattenedAttributes: "",
  attributes : [] 
}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "port to javascript"?  Are you trying to query Web SQL?  Are you querying objects in memory?

Comment: @BenCollins I am dealing with objects in memory, trying to find the optimal way to filter my dataset using memory based constructs.

Comment: I suggest then that you edit your question to say something more like "How do I filter objects in javascript using the same logic as what's in this SQL query?"  Other question guidelines still apply, of course.  Read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully, and then edit your question and it may get reopened.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From my understanding what the SQL query was doing is set intersection, which is why it is so dang fast. underscore has a function for this too which is what I ended up using _.intersection

Answer (score 1):

I'm no SQL wizard, but I think this simulates your query:

```
var result = _.chain(data)
.filter(function (v) {
    return _.contains(v.attributes, 1) || _.contains(v.attributes, 2)
})
.pluck('fruitId')
.countBy()
.reduce(function (m, v, k) {
    if (v >= 2) {
        m.push(+k);
    }
    return m;
}, [])
.value();
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yc98z/) (that doesn't do much, 'cause of the small data set).  While underscore seems adequate for this task, you could also look into something like TaffyDB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version using underscore. It wont be as efficient as custom javascript but it is easier on the eye:

```
var applesAndBananas = function(fruit){
    return fruit.fruitId == 1 || fruit.fruitId == 2;
}

var moreThanOneFruit = function(groupedFruit){
    return groupedFruit.length > 1;
}

var getFruitId = function(groupedFruits){
    return groupedFruits[0].fruitId;
}

var fruitIds = _.chain(fruits)
    .filter(applesAndBananas)
    .groupBy('fruitId')
    .filter(moreThanOneFruit)
    .map(getFruitId)
    .value();
```